# CustomField in django model getting value

Tags: django

I have something like this:

```
class Test(models.Model):
    testField = MyCustomField('my field')


class MyCustomField(models.CharField):
    description = "some description"

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(models.CharField, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

class TestForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model=Test
```

Can i read in django template value of description field?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`form["testField"]` (or `{{ form.testField }}` in a template) will yield a `BoundField` (cf https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/ref/forms/api/#django.forms.BoundField).

To access the `Field` object itself you need `form["testField"].field` (or `{{ form.testField.field }}` - or just `{{ field.field }}` if you're iterating on the form's bouldfields - in the template).

Also there's a bug in your call to `super()`, it should be:

```
super(MyCustomField, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
```

not

```
super(Models.CharField, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
```

**And finally**: the form's fields are NOT the model's fields. If `{{ field }}` is one of your form's fields, it's just a totally different (and unrelated) object.

Comment: I know that {{field}} is not {{field.field}}.. I corrected my bug and still nothing :(

Comment: I dont think you read the full updated answer. Your "custom field" is a **model** field, not a **form** field. The matching form field is a plain `forms.CharField` and has no "description" attribute.

Comment: Ok, understand. Can i make it work? Maybe custom tag?

Comment: You obviously have to write a custom form field. Or find another solution to your problem, whatever it is. FWIW : what's your use case for a _class level_ "description" attribute ?

Comment: Ok, understand now. Just another question, is there way to make custom Form but with model included?

Comment: Got it now! I can solve this by hidden fields. Thank you very much!